# Can I swap the positions of the toilet and bath tub?

Tags: plumbing

We do not like where the toilet and bath tub are now located in the master bathroom. Can I place the toilet where the bath tub drain is now, and install a new bath tub where the toilet currently is? This would also enable us to enlarge the small stand up shower.

Answer (score 3):

It's not going to be easy, but it's *possible*. The toilet drain pipe is going to be 3", and won't have a trap (since the trap is built into the toilet). The toilet will also only have a cold water supply. The tub drain pipe will likely be 1 1/2", and will have a trap. The tub will obviously have both cold and hot water supplies.

To switch the location of the fixtures, you'll have to reroute the plumbing for each to the new locations. Depending on the current location of the fixtures, existing plumbing, and the amount of access to the plumbing. This job could range anywhere from not so bad, to a complete gut and rebuild.

Comment: Good answer. Your biggest issue will be to reroute the drainage pipe for the toilet, this is much larger (at least 6" in the UK) and harder to re-route, the drainage for the bathtub, is a smaller plastic pipe. Routing the hot water is not too difficult and you can extend from the current pipe.